# Simple GET request in cURL is unresponsive

Tags: python, http, curl, flask

I wrote python code for a very basic server to test cURL on my terminal (Mac OS X)

```
from flask import Flask
node = Flask(__name__)

@node.route('/greet', methods=['GET'])
def greet(): 
    print "hello, world"
    return "hey!"
node.run()
```

However, when I ran the code on my terminal, using

```
$ python testblock.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Everything worked fine when I copied and pasted the url (http://127.0.0.1:5000/greet) into my web browser, but when I ran the following command:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/greet
```

and I hit enter, nothing happens, and I just get a cursor on the terminal. Is there something wrong with the way I requested the page in my terminal? Thank you so much!

Comment: I copy pasted your code exactly and `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/greet` worked perfectly on my system. But the "hey!" is printed without a newline character so it kinda gets prepended to my bash prompt like so: `hey!nitred@nitred-pc$ `. I hope you ran the `curl` command in a new terminal?

Comment: @Nitred, I ran it in a new terminal window, and the same thing happened.

Comment: Maybe try with `node.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=True)`. BTW when you're using `curl` do you see `hello world` being printed on the terminal where the server is running i.e. the terminal where `python testblock.py` is running?

Comment: Your code is fine in my machine. Tested both using browser and curl.

Comment: @Nitred - I tried changing the argument for node.run(), and nothing happens still. And no, I don't see "hello world" printed on the terminal where the server is running.

Comment: Can you use `curl` to get anything else?

Comment: @dvnguyen, I can. I used  `curl https://curl.haxx.se` and it returned the html of that webpage (this is curl's GET example [link](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#GET))

Comment: In addition, I updated my flask to the most recent version last night. I'll try restarting my computer, as well.

Comment: Can you run `curl` in verbose mode and paste the log here? `curl --verbose http://127.0.0.1:5000/greet`

Comment: @dvnguyen, here's my log:

`$ python test.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 213-637-690
curl --verbose http://0.0.0.0:5050/greet

`

in addition, here's a [screenshot](https://puu.sh/yOULg/0058566b18.png)

Comment: I guess I know why. Are you writing `curl ...` right after the flask log? If you run `curl` in a new terminal tab/window, I think it will be fine.

Comment: BTW, instead of `node.run()`, I wrote `node.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=True)`

Comment: @dvnguyen, ah, I tried your suggestion, and it worked. Why is it that you have to run the curl command in a new tab? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Actually after you run `python test.py`, the Python process is still running and hasn't returned, so the current terminal window can't receive any other inputs.